# When in the release process should I minify my css and js files?

Tags: php, release, rsync, minify, yui-compressor

Currently we have a very simple (but effective) release process. We tag a new version in SVN. This version will is exported to a test environment. From there we rsync to the Acceptance environment and from there to Production.

Now we want to start minifying css and js files. I wanted to do this minifying on our test-environment in the process of releasing to Acceptance, so that both on the Acceptance environment and Production environment we have minified files. However, if I minify the files there, the timestamps change, and rsync will every time transfer ALL css and js files, even though the minified content hasn't changed.

My question is: what is best practice to solve this? 
Should I use a different mechanism than rsync to release a new version? 
Should I put the minified versions in SVN already? But I don't want minified files in development, so what is the best moment to minify (and possibly combine) them?

We use PHP 5.3.6 and I started looking at Yui-compressor because I can easily use it in scripts.

Comment: And what is the problem in syncing every time those mifieds files?

Comment: One problem is that it makes the release slower. But more importantly,  seeing the list of changed files is the last check that you're releasing ONLY what you intended to. We like to have multiple ways to make sure that we don't make mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

You should only minify the files again when the timestamp on the source files is newer than the timestamp on the already minified files. If you do that, rsync will work just fine and only transfer changed files.

If you use build software like Apache Ant or Phing this should be quite easy to achieve. They have testst specifically to detect timestamp changes.

Comment: When I get a new version from SVN into the test environment, all files are not-minified. This means that I need to minify EVERY file, whether it's changed in this new version or not, resulting in all timestamps being updated.

Comment: I was hoping there would be some solution in rsync that results in not updating a file if the content hasn't changed. Or maybe, I should create a separate release version in SVN that is minified. Or maybe minifying is just something that should be done on-the-fly through Apache? I just don't know what's best practice

Comment: I think rsync can detect file changes, but maybe only when you use the rsync daemon and not when you just use plain SSH. Rsync can do rolling checksums in order to minimize traffic.